# Char string review

Tags: c++, strings

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) //give the user 4 guesses at the word.
    {   
        std::string guess; 
        cout <<"Guess the word" <<endl;
        cin >>guess;

        if (guess == "Dog")
        {
            cout <<"You guessed correctly. " <<endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"You guessed incorrectly. " <<endl;
        }
    }
    char f;
    cin >>f;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`#include "stdafx.h"` is superfluous.

The standard idiom in C++ for doing something 4 times is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Don't deviate from that pattern unless there is a good reason.

Requiring an extra character input to exit the program is a weird user experience, especially since there is no prompt.  I would just get rid of `char f; cin >> f;`.

Comment: With such a "pause" in place, it's fair to assume the OP is using an IDE (probably with no built-in pause).  It is also much better than `system("PAUSE")`.

Comment: @Jamal That makes sense. (I usually don't use an IDE.) In that case, a comment would be useful: `// Pause so that output can be examined when running in an IDE`

Comment: Fair enough.  You may add that to your answer, especially for others not too familiar with such IDEs.

Answer (score 5):

- [Try not to use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- Be sure to include `<string>` since you're using `std::string`.
- Prefer [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) over `operator>>` for all user input into an `std::string`:

  ```
  std::getline(std::cin, guess);
  ```
- If you want to avoid case-sensitivity issues, I'd recommend having both `guess` and the word in the same case (lowercase or uppercase).

  You can use [`std::transform()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) on `guess` to make it lowercase or uppercase, and have the word provided in the same case:

  ```
  // get the input

  // transform the guess string to all lowercase
  std::transform(guess.begin(), guess.end(), guess.begin(), ::tolower);

  if (guess == "dog")
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- The "pause" at the end is okay, but here's another one:

  ```
  std::cin.get();
  ```

  This one doesn't involve an extra variable, although it doesn't really matter.  The program still "waits" for user input before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. Don't know what the last `cin >> f` is for but the function runs well. Just a tip, you don't need to include the `std::` scope in front of `string guess`, as you've already declared that you're `using namespace std.`

Comment: Note he should not be using `using namespace std;` so prefer to add `std::` to all the places it has been left off. The `cin >> f` forces the application to pause until the user hits return. If running in a hosted environment this prevents the window from closing too quickly to see the answer.